# an illustrative guide to master the spree e-commerce

Tags: e-commerce, spree

i am newbie to spree e-commerce, after  reading many queries & answers i understood that using spree is not easy for our custom needs of e-commerce sites. anyhow, is there any illustrative guide ( other than spree official guide) /tutorial to learn & use the spree e-commerce effectively ? plz., inform

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you're correc tin that Spree is not "easy." This is because Spree was made "by developers for developers." If you don't have an extensive knowledge of rails, or want a ecommerce solution that doesn't require much coding, Spree is certainly not for you.